# Deploying ASP.NET Core project with TeamCity and ignore tests - WebDeploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a very simple scenario. I have a ASP.NET Core project (.NET Framework) with a PublishProfile for WebDeploy. I have also .NET Core Class Library project (.Net Framework) which references my service, it's my test project. When I build this solution on TeamCity I have a Visual Studio Build step with some additional parameters for webdeploy, among others /p:DeployOnBuild=true. The problem however is that DeployOnBuild is a global setting so it will apply for all "service" projects. I don't know why but my Test Project is treaten as publishable so it will try to deploy test project as well and it ends up with an error that it cannot find a publish profile in test project. How can I tell in .sln or in .xproj that this is not publishable project and I don't want it to be a part of publish process? I found some workarounds to ignore services project but this is a very simple scenario so I reckon that I shouldn't be using any hacks to achieve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that as you target .sln in your deploy step, you are telling him to deploy any deployable projet inside .sln file.
Did you try to target the project file instead ?

I am not using the Visual Studio Build step but it works with MSBuild :
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0JKe.png)

Comment: Yes I tried it. The issue here is that I can't build this project alone because there is a postbuild step in this project which copies some files and I get an error that it cannot copy these files because path cannot be found. It looks like $(SolutionDir) is not set in this project properly when I build it separately. This post build event is part of one of referenced nuget packages. Do you happen to know how is "deployable" project recognized?

Comment: I have not try it on my own but maybe if you create a build configuration `deployment` that only build the webapp with any needed dependencies except your test projet then use the switch `/p:Configuration=deployment` on TeamCity ?

Comment: thanks for that. Anyway that's one of the workarounds I wanted to avoid. I thought that there should be an easier way than this.